# Global operators and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operators

I have two classes, with two global `friend oparator<<`s.

```
class A {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const A &a);
};

class B: public A {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const B &b);
};
```

If i use it like this, everything is working fine, the `B` version of the operator gets called:

```
B b;
std::cout << b;
```

But if i use polymorpism, the `A` version gets called, although the dynamic type is `B`:

```
A* b = new B();
std::cout << *b;
```

One solution is casting:

```
std::cout << static_cast<B&>(*b);
```

but is there any simpler or more elegant solution for this?

Comment: What about invoking a virtual function in the `operator <<(std::ostream&, A const&)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. One output operator and `virtual print` function in classes.

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual ~A() {}
private:
   virtual void print(std::ostream&) {}
   friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A& obj)
   {
      obj.print(os);
      return os;
   }
};

class B
{
private:
   virtual void print(std::ostream&) {}
};
```

[Live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6UxBr%243)

Comment: please add the `return os;` to the friend function.

Comment: please remove the `friend` from that function - it need not be a friend but can be a free function ;)

Comment: @ArneMertz print is private. How operator << can be free function in this case? And why we need print in public?

Comment: so why make `print` private, since it does nothing private? make it public, since it is the function that does the work and should be part of the class' public interface. The `operator<<` is only syntactic sugar to beautify the code, not a VIP that should have access to *anything* inside A.

Answer (score 3):

Versions of functions in derived classes are only called when you access them via a pointer to the base class if you define them as `virtual` because the compiler hasn't a clue what the class of the object pointed to by the pointer actually is.

Here the trouble is that you are defining friend functions so they cannot themselves be virtual, the solution is simple: have the implementation of A's `operator<<` call a virtual function in `A` that you can then overload in `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't use friends. They are a even tighter coupling than inheritance. An especially if you write those friend operators for class templates one could specialize it and legally gain access to your class' internals. For those reasons I use those operators only as syntactic sugar and let them delegate to member functions that do the real work. That way the solution to your problem is a no-brainer:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual std::ostream& printToStream(std::ostream& os) const;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& a)
{ return a.printToStream(os); }
```

---

```
class B: public A {
  virtual std::ostream& printToStream(std::ostream& os) const;
};
```

Have another class C derived from A? No problem, no need to define the syntactic sugar (i.e. `operator<<`) again, just define how the real work is done, i.e. override `printToStream` - that's the reason why I made it virtual.